# Clunking noise on Schwinn Meridian

Tags: noise, schwinn

I have a brand new Schwinn Meridian 26" 7 speed.  I had a bike shop assemble it.  It works fine but a clunking noise comes from the back end when I am riding it.  Solutions?

Comment: You will need to add more details. All we know is a clunking noise, back end, while riding. So we cannot even fathom a solution as we still can not identify the problem.  Is it just a noise, or can you feel something too?  Is it while pedaling, coasting, or both?  Is it only in one gear or any gear? Is there anything loose that you can detect?  Really give us as MUCH telemetry as you can so we can start to offer solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information given, I would suggest taking it back to the bike shop that assembled it to resolve the clunking issue. The shop is supposed to deliver you a safe, functional bicycle, not a defective one.